# Inserting images into using java swing

Tags: java

I'm trying to insert an image into resource folder and use it to display in frame. But I'm getting this error :

> Type Mismatch: can't convert from java.awt.Image to project.image

Comment: Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [How to Use Icons](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/icon.html) for working examples. We have no idea what "project.image" is or why you are trying to convert it. So start with working code and make changes as required.

Comment: @jaas : Could you please show us your code ?

Comment: @jaas : Probably you have a class `Image` . remove it.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a example using an image icon from the default java resources.

```
    JLabel lblNewLabel = new JLabel("");
    lblNewLabel.setIcon(new ImageIcon(test.class.getResource("/com/sun/java/swing/plaf/windows/icons/Question.gif")));
    lblNewLabel.setBounds(112, 60, 151, 126);
    frmTitle.getContentPane().add(lblNewLabel);
```

the code above will add a question mark image on your application, like this [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HpLlC.png). You can of course change it to whatever you would like.

Answer (score 0):

Hope this simple sample helps you...

```
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.FontMetrics;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Image;
import java.awt.Toolkit;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.KeyAdapter;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyListener;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseListener;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.*;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class FloorPlaner extends JFrame {
     protected BufferedImage wall;

     public FloorPlaner(){ 
          super("FloorPlaner");
          try {
          wall = ImageIO.read(new File ("wall.png")); //Load a wall
          } catch(IOException bug) { //Create a wall image
          wall=new BufferedImage(20, 20, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
          Graphics2D wg=wall.createGraphics();
          wg.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
          wg.setColor(Color.BLACK);
          wg.fillRect(0,0,20,20);
          System.out.println(bug);
          }

          requestFocus(); 

          setContentPane(new DrawingPane());

          setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE); 

          setSize(400, 400);

          setResizable(true); 

          setVisible(true); 

          while (true) { 
              repaint();
              try {
              Thread.sleep(40); //25 FPS
              } catch(InterruptedException bug) {
              Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
              System.out.println(bug);
              }
          }
     }


     class DrawingPane extends JPanel { //Where you actually draw on
        public void paintComponent(Graphics g) { //Drawing method
           g.drawImage(wall,0,0,null);
        }   
     }
     public static void main(String args[]) {
            new FloorPlaner(); //Start it
     }
}
```